# Stored scrollbar position starts at the top on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, scrollbar, session-storage

I have a scrolling div with some links and I want to store the scrollbar position on click and keep the position after page load. This code does the work but when the new page loads the scrollbar starts at the top and immediately goes to it's stored position.

It works well in Microsoft EDGE, but it doesn't in Chrome.

Is there a way to avoid that? I don't want any scrollbar/content movement on page load.

Here's an example.

```
$('.sidebar a').click(function() {
  sessionStorage.scrollTop = $('.sidebar').scrollTop();
});

if (sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
  $('.sidebar').scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollTop);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/549685/

Comment: *"when the new page loads"* You are losing the sessionStorage so maybe using localStorage might be a better option for you?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Still the same, when you click "go to link" there's a slightly scrollbar/content movement.